# Rearrange values displayed in firebase realtime database from google sheets script

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I want to change how my values are displayed in the firebase realtime database. They are showing as numbers and I want the title of the column displayed.

**script text:**

```
var secret = 'xxxx'


function getFirebaseUrl(jsonPath) {

  /*
  We then make a URL builder
  This takes in a path, and
  returns a URL that updates the data in that path
  */

  return (

    'https://no-excusas.firebaseio.com/' +

    jsonPath +
    '.json?auth=' +
    secret
  )
}

function syncMasterSheet(excelData) {

  /*
  We make a PUT (update) request,
  and send a JSON payload
  More info on the REST API here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start
  */

  var options = {

    method: 'put',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: JSON.stringify(excelData)
  }

  var fireBaseUrl = getFirebaseUrl('Users')


  /*
  We use the UrlFetchApp google scripts module
  More info on this here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app
  */

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(fireBaseUrl, options)

}

function startSync() {

  //Get the currently active sheet

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()

  //Get the number of rows and columns which contain some content

  var [rows, columns] = [sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()]


  //Get the data contained in those rows and columns as a 2 dimensional array

  var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows, columns).getValues()


  //Use the syncMasterSheet function defined before to push this data to the "masterSheet" key in the firebase database

  syncMasterSheet(data)

}
```

**screenshot of firebase database:**
[image: screenshot of firebase database]

**screenshot of spreadsheet:**
[image: screenshot of spreadsheet]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is getting pushed to the Firebase database in the format you're sending -- the return value of `Range.getValues()` is an `Object[][]` (see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues())).

The fix is to just munge the data into the format you want.  Based on your description, I think you're fine with the top level of the array being numbers (e.g. array indexes), but you want the inside of each item to be labeled the same as the columns.

I won't copy all your code, only the 2 functions that need changes.  First, `startSync` should grab the header row and the data rows separately (assuming you don't want an item for the header row itself in the database):

```js
function startSync() {
  //Get the currently active sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()

  //Get the number of rows and columns which contain some content

  var [rows, columns] = [sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()]

  // Get the data contained in those rows and columns as a 2 dimensional array.
  // Get the headers in a separate array.
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, columns).getValues()[0];  // [0] to unwrap the outer array
  var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows - 1, columns).getValues();  // skipping the header row means we need to reduce rows by 1.

  //Use the syncMasterSheet function defined before to push this data to the "masterSheet" key in the firebase database

  syncMasterSheet(headers, data)
}
```

Second, `syncMasterSheet()` should build the object you want to PUT before doing the PUT:

```js
function syncMasterSheet(sheetHeaders, sheetData) {
  /*
  We make a PUT (update) request,
  and send a JSON payload
  More info on the REST API here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start
  */              
  const outputData = [];
  for(i = 0; i < sheetData.length; i++) {
      var row = sheetData[i];
      var newRow = {};
      for(j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
        newRow[sheetHeaders[j]] = row[j];
      }
      outputData.push(newRow);
  }

  var options = {
    method: 'put',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: JSON.stringify(outputData)
  }

  var fireBaseUrl = getFirebaseUrl('SpreadsheetTest')

  /*
  We use the UrlFetchApp google scripts module
  More info on this here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app
  */
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(fireBaseUrl, options)
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm exactly how I needed and expected, thanks mate and for the description as well